# What is the difference between those two join usage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, arraylist

Could anyone simply explain why the first method doesnt work as expected but inside console.log works perfect?

Simply I expected that It needs to return string but returns array in the first console

```js
var elements = ['Fire', 'Wind', 'Rain'];

elements.join(''); //why that one is not working?

console.log(elements);
// expected output: Fire,Wind,Rain

console.log(elements.join(''));
// expected output: FireWindRain
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `elements.join('');` to a variable:

```
var elements = ['Fire', 'Wind', 'Rain'];

elements = elements.join('');

console.log(elements);
```